# How to show the cart items in the Personalized Module, and send by email

Tags: magento2

How can I get the cart items in a Customized module? I need in my module on a certain page to show all the items that are in the cart, so that I can send them by email.

Comment: using customer session, is it cannot be done ?   we have sales module that keeps track or order history and sales_order related table in database. You may check there.